# When does the anonymous objects get deleted from memory and when it is recommended to use them?

Tags: c++

I am new to c++ and i was trying to understand constructors and destructors and little bit about memory management. In the below code everything is working fine for me except for

**1.MyClass().disp();
 2.new MyClass;
 3.new MyClass(300);**

1)I want to know is it correct to call all three of these as anonymous object.
2) For MyClass(), I understood that this creates an object and immediately destroys it so there is no problem of memory.
But for new MyClass() the destructor is never called. I also understand that because this is on heap I will have to delete the object explicitly. But how do i do that in this case?
And if it is not possible when will that memory get free after the program execution?
3) Also i wanted to know the scenarios where such type of object creation(new MyClass) can be useful.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;

class MyClass
{
private:
    int num;
public:
    MyClass()
    {
        cout<<"no-arg constructor"<<endl;
    }
    MyClass(int num)
    {
        this->num=num;
        cout<<"one param constructor"<<endl;
    }
    ~MyClass()
    {
        cout<<"inside destructor\t"<<num<<endl;
    }
    void disp()
    {
        cout<<num<<endl;
    }
 };

int main()
{
    MyClass m1;
    MyClass m2(200);

    MyClass *m3=new MyClass;
    MyClass *m4=new MyClass(400);

    MyClass().disp();
    new MyClass;
    new MyClass(300);

    delete m4;
    delete m3;
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: You have a memory leak. `new MyClass(300);` allocates memory that is never freed.

Comment: There lots of problems with this code, including multiple memory leaks, a lack of exception-safety, and an incorrect signature for the `main` method. Why are you writing this code? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @CodyGray: To me it looks like concrete example code for a question about lifetimes.

Comment: @Asim: Please, in future questions do not post code with `void main`. It's non-standard so with many compilers the code will simply not compile. Both C and C++ require `int main`.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf.. Ok ill keep that in mind. This is the code which i just copied and i was making changes in it to understand things. Forgot to change the signature of the main.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

“Anonymous object” is not a standard term, it's a descriptive term. I would interpret it as an object without a name. Objects with names are called variables or data members.

1. In the expression `MyClass().disp()` you're calling the member function `disp` on a **temporary object** of class `MyClass`. The lifetime of the temporary object extends <sup>[1]</sup>to the end of the full expression. Which in C++ standardese, if I recall correctly, is called the *full-expression*.
2. The `new`-expression `new MyClass` allocates memory for a new `MyClass` object, and creates a new `MyClass` object in that chunk of memory. The expression produces a pointer to the new object. You can store that pointer in a variable and use it in a later `delete` expression to destroy the object and deallocate its memory.
3. The expression `new MyClass(300)` is the same except an argument is provided for the `MyClass` constructor. The `new`-expression syntax also provides a notation to specify arguments to the allocation operation. But that's more advanced, very seldom needed, and anyway, as a beginner you should preferentially never use raw `new` or `delete`, but instead standard library containers and strings.

If there is no corresponding `delete` for a `new` then the object lives till the end of the program execution. If this is a machine with an operating system then the OS will reclaim the memory. However, the OS knows nothing about C++ objects so the object destructor is then not called, and hence cleanup specified in the destructor will not be performed.

You ask where `new` is useful. Generally when the desired lifetime for an object does not fit a scope (the nested lifetimes of local automatic variables), and/or where one needs a dynamic size object. Using `new` to control lifetime is less of an issue with efficiently movable objects as in C++11 and later, and for dynamic size preferentially use containers such as `std::vector` and strings like `std::string`.

<sup><sup>[1]</sup> More generally a temporary object can be bound directly to a local reference, in which case its lifetime is extended to the lifetime of the reference, i.e. out the enclosing block.</sup>

Comment: Hi @Alf, Thanks for the answer. Almost everything is clear now but just cannot understand when should i use object without name. I am assuming that when i want to use the class method only once then instead of creating a variable which will hold my object i will create anonymous object and call my method...like i did in my code i.e MyClass().disp. but i have no idea when is it beneficial to use (new Myclass)->disp. It is allowed and therefore i am assuming that there must be some scenario when it would be preferred over Myclass *ptr = new Myclass(); then ptr->disp().

Comment: @Asim: There are scenarios such as with self-destroying objects used in some old GUI frameworks you could reasonably do things like `(new T)->method()`. But for now, just keep in mind that (1) doing dynamic allocation is zillions of times slower than e.g. multiplication, not as exceedingly slow as file i/o but still really undesirably slow by C++ standards (in other languages such operations are regarded as free, in C++ they're compared to very efficient stuff!), and (2) `new` is an invitation to bugs. Very difficult to get right. And you don't need it yet.

Comment: Simply declaring a variable is a good way to create an object.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you would allocate objects on the stack, because it is faster, and you do not need to delete it.

However, if you want to return a pointer you must allocate it on the heap. For example

```
int *foo(int n)
{
    int *pn = new int(n);
    return pn;
}
```

Now the caller is responsible for freeing the memory.

```
int main()
{
    try {
        int *ptr = foo(6);

        // use ptr

       delete ptr;
   } catch (std::bad_alloc &ba) {
       std::cerr << ba.what() << '\n';
   }
}
```

Your mistake is to not store the return value of `new`. Without storing the return value, how will you use the memory? How will you free it? It's like paying for a ticket to the movies, but then throwing it out.

Your program has other mistakes. `main` must return `int`, not `void`. It is also a better idea to use the standard `getchar` function instead of `getch`.

I also added exception handling to the code, because `new` throws an exception when it can't allocate. Wrapping the entire `main` function code in a `try` block is a common idiom in C++ code.

Comment: While factually correct, it would have been more constructive to advocate for `std::unique_ptr` as a resource owning handle, instead of a raw pointer.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Cheers and hth. - Alf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35254284/1621391)'s answer, I will however add this...

If you **really want** *and* **have** to create a temporary object of class `Bar` on the heap, just use [std::make_shared](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) (C++11) or [std::make_unique](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) (C++14)....

Example:

```
std::make_unique<Bar>()->foo()
std::make_shared<Bar>()->foo()
```

The above creates `Bar` and calls it's method `foo()`. `Bar`'s destructor is called after `foo()` completes, and invariably its associated memory deleted....

Its possible to code a simple class and function like that in older C++ but, it can't be generic because of [variadic templates](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments) and [perfect forwarding](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward)

Free advice: Avoid any circumstances that ever requires the above... even the code below (supposedly more efficient than heap) is usually frowned at in code reviews

```
Bar().foo()
```

Answer (score 0):

3)Newed object can still be referenced through `this`, so you can do `(1)` or `(2)`, or just pass pointer as argument or return from function `(3)`.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class MyClass;
std::vector<MyClass*> vec;

class MyClass {
    public:
    // (1)
    MyClass() { std::cout << 'c'; vec.push_back(this); }
    ~MyClass() { std::cout << 'd'; }

    // OR (2)
    MyClass* doSmth() { /* do some work; */ return this; }
    void destroy() { delete this; }

    // OR (3)
    static void doAndDelete(MyClass* p)
    {
        // do smth
        delete p;
    }
    static MyClass* creator() { return new MyClass; }
};

int main() {
    // (1)
    new MyClass;
    for (auto x : vec)
        delete x;
    vec.clear();

    // OR (2)
    (new MyClass())->doSmth()->destroy();

    // OR (3)
    MyClass::doAndDelete(new MyClass);
    MyClass* p = MyClass::creator();
    delete p;
}
```

can sometimes be useful